# Local cohomology of codimension $2$ subvariety and relationship with cohomology of its normal bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic $0$.
Consider the closed subvariety $\mathbb{A}^1_{k}$ of $\mathbb{A}^3_{k}$.

By the local cohomology theory, we have the cohomology sequence
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
0 &\rightarrow H^0_{\mathbb{A}^1}(\mathbb{A}^3, \mathcal{O}) \rightarrow H^0(\mathbb{A}^3, \mathcal{O}) \rightarrow H^0(\mathbb{A}^3 \setminus \mathbb{A}^1, \mathcal{O}) \\
 &\rightarrow H^1_{\mathbb{A}^1}(\mathbb{A}^3, \mathcal{O}) \rightarrow H^1(\mathbb{A}^3, \mathcal{O}).
\end{split}
\end{equation}

It is well known that $H^1(\mathbb{A}^3, \mathcal{O}) = 0$, and by Hartogs theorem, we have
$H^0(\mathbb{A}^3, \mathcal{O}) \simeq H^0(\mathbb{A}^3 \setminus \mathbb{A}^1, \mathcal{O})$.
Therefore, we must have $$ H^1_{\mathbb{A}^1}(\mathbb{A}^3,\mathcal{O}) = 0.$$

On the other hand, there is the short exact sequence
$$0 \rightarrow I_{\mathbb{A}^1}^n \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^3} \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^3}/I_{\mathbb{A}^1}^n \rightarrow 0$$
which induces the cohomology sequence
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
0 &\rightarrow \mathcal{H}om(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^3}/I_{\mathbb{A}^1}^n, \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^3}) \rightarrow \mathcal{H}om(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^3}, \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^3}) \rightarrow \mathcal{H}om(I_{\mathbb{A}^1}^n, \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^3})\\
&\rightarrow \mathcal{E}xt^1(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^3}/I_{\mathbb{A}^1}^n, \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^3}) \rightarrow 0.
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Since $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^3}$ is locally free, $\mathcal{H}om(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^3}/I_{\mathbb{A}^1}^n, \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^3}) = 0$.

By local cohomology theory again, there exists an isomorphism
$$\varinjlim Ext^i_{\mathcal{O}}(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^3}/I_{\mathbb{A}^1}^n, \mathcal{O}) \xrightarrow{\sim} H^i_{\mathbb{A}^1}(\mathbb{A^3, \mathcal{O}}).$$

Therefore,we have $\mathcal{E}xt^1(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^3}/I_{\mathbb{A}^1}^n, \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^3})=0$, and the morphism $\mathcal{H}om(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^3}, \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^3}) \rightarrow \mathcal{H}om(I_{\mathbb{A}^1}^n, \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^3})$ should be isomorphism for sufficiently large $n$.

My question is

***Can we prove this isomorphism
$\mathcal{H}om(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^3}, \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^3})
 \rightarrow \mathcal{H}om(I_{\mathbb{A}^1}^n,
 \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^3})$ directly?***

***Is the argument so far correct?***

The motivation of this question is that I heard that there exists an isomorphism
$$ \varinjlim H^{i-1}(Y, N_{nY}) \xrightarrow{\sim} H^i_Y(X, \mathcal{O})$$
for closed subvariety $Y \subset X$.
However, applying this isomorphism to the above discussion, we have
$$ Ext^1(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^3}/I_{\mathbb{A}^1}^n, \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^3}) \simeq H^0(\mathbb{A}^1, N_{n\mathbb{A}^1}) \neq 0$$
which is a contradiction.

So, I want to understand the relation between $H^{i-1}(Y, N_{nY})$ and $H^i_Y(X, \mathcal{O})$ more clearly.